# Slow rendering using "Sans-Serif"

Tags: html, css

I have a odd issue on my "in-development" website here: http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/stage/

The H1-h6 fonts are just "sans-serif", but often in Chrome it shows another font (screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/260B0H0l1w0C). When the mouse hover the navigation it changes to the right font. FYI this is how it should look like: http://cl.ly/image/442l071M3N1B

The code used for font is:

```
.nm li a {
    float: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height:22px;
    padding: 12px 14px 7px 14px;
    color:@white;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

I mainly develop using Chrome, so I'm not sure if the issue is present in other browsers. Have anyone of you seen this issue before?

Comment: This is not Twitter. Please do not shorten your URLs, and include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Now edited. Those remaining links are not shorturls (or at least the service dont provide other urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'sans-serif' is not a font name it's a font family specification.

Use a sans-serif font name like "Arial" or "Verdana" or else you will have unexpected results (the browser may replace your font with generic ones).

Answer (score 0):

Try using custom font method by downloading the font and keeping it in your fonts folder.

Example:

```
@font-face {
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url('Sansation_Light.ttf')
    ,url('Sansation_Light.eot'); /* IE9 */
}

div
{ font-family:myFirstFont; }
```

Comment: But I dont need any custom fonts (I already use that for webfonts). It would be smarter to save that http-request I think

Answer (score 0):

Try using custom web font from google:

http://www.google.com/fonts

Select a font and uses one of the three metods, i prefer CSS method.

Example:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
```

Import this in CSS and use this for you text: `font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;`